# How to extract array from json on Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, observable

I'm working with angular2 ( version 5). 
I make an http request an get back json.
I know how to access and use value but not the array. 
 and I don't find how to extract the two array inside element.

here my json:

```
{ "ImpiantiProva": [
        {
        "nomeImpianto":"MFL1",
        "descrImpianto":"Multifilo 1",
        "posizione":"Place1",
        "dati_status": "true",
        "unita_misura": "m/s",
        "vel_attuale": 11.5,

        "vel": [24.5,13.6,34.6,12.1],
        "orario": ["17.05","17.06","17.07","17.08"]
        },  

        {
        "nomeImpianto":"MFL2",
        "descrImpianto":"Multifilo 2",
        "posizione":"Place2",
        "dati_status": "true",
        "unita_misura": "m/s",
        "vel_attuale": 12.5,

        "vel": [24.5,13.6,34.6,12.1],
        "orario": ["17.05","17.06","17.07","17.08"]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the data.service.ts I have the http request and it store values on :

```
stream$: Observable<ImpiantoModel[]>;
```

here my definition of the model:

```
#impianto.model
export class ImpiantoModel {
  nomeImpianto: string;
  descrImpianto: string;
  posizione: string;
  dati_status: string;
  unita_misura: string;
  vel_attuale: number;
  vel: VelocitaModel[];
  orario: OrariModel[];
}


 #orari.model.ts
export class OrariModel {
  orario: string;
}


  #velocita.model.ts
export class VelocitaModel{
  vel : number;
}
```

is it the right why to define my object?

How can I use the array `"vel"` and `"orario"`?

How can I print (access) the array `"vel"` of machine with `"nomeImpianto" = "MFL1"` ?

and how can I copy the array `"vel"` on new array?

thank you very much!

Comment: you want to see in HTML template/

Comment: What does this question have to do with Angular or observable pattern? As far as I can tell, you're asking a plain JavaScript question about filtering an array. Is that correct?

Comment: @Lazar I have a type Observable and I have to manage array on html template and copy it to another component

Comment: @sajeetharan yes, it's one of my goals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I understood of what you want to do : get the item in your json resp and put it in your object , so the best way is to create a static method directly when you get the json response, before returning the value create this adapter adaptImpiant(jsonObj) which will do something like :

```
adaptImpiant(jsonObj) {
    let impiantTab = [];
    jsonObj.ImpiantiProva.forEach((item) => {
      let impiantoModel = {};
      // impiantoModel = item if the model (below) match the item;
      // if not manually set all your var like your velocita
      let velocita =  [] // is an array or an object with an array
      // if class velocita = {} 
      velocita = item.vel.slice(0); 
      // if class velocita.valuesTab = item.vel.slice(0);
      impiantoModel.velocita = velocita;
      impiantTab.push(impiantoModel);
    }    
}
```

Your model seems wrong in this case, because you already use a ImpiantoModel array, so just create a class with whatever you want in :

```
#impianto.model
export class ImpiantoModel {
   nomeImpianto: string;
   descrImpianto: string;
   posizione: string;
   dati_status: string;
   unita_misura: string;
   vel_attuale: number;
   vel: VelocitaModel // or simply [];
   orario: OrariModel // or simply [];
}
```

Comment: Hello @andrea06590! 
I think that I can't use your solution because on array "vel" and "orario" I have over than 10k values. I have to create the new array for a charts on new component, and when I want to see the charts (user click) I extract the data from my Observable. 

I upload my [code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/extract-array-from-json-on-angular)  so you can see! I make http request and I find how to print my array on html template!

Comment: But I can't fine how to copy array "vel" to new array. ( see function <code> copyArrary() </code> on <code>app.component.ts</code>. I need to extract array for use the value on other component for generare a charts and I need a array for all the value.

Do you know how can I do? thank you very much!

Comment: Just push your impiantoModel in impiantTab ;) 
You can also get a full copy of the vel table using newVel = vel.slice(0)
See answer edited

Comment: I upload my (code here)[https://stackblitz.com/edit/extract-array-from-json-on-angular]. I don't understand how get a copy of vel. So I have to declare an array newArray: Array<number>; and now? Where can I make the copy? On http request as you said? Grazie per l'aiuto!!

Comment: with your code I managed to complete my intent! in the code below, the array "newArray" is a copy of the speedy array of my json! it does not matter if you rewrite it every time, I can get the data I want in this way! thank you so much! you saved my day!
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/extract-array-from-json-on-angular-xfxhto)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you, but I'll try.

> is it the right why to define my object?

It should be:

```
export class ImpiantoModel {
  nomeImpianto: string;
  descrImpianto: string;
  posizione: string;
  dati_status: string;
  unita_misura: string;
  vel_attuale: number;
  vel: Array<string>;
  orario: Array<string>;
}
```

(But I have to confess, I don't know why model and not an interface)

> How can I use the array "vel" and "orario"?

What do you mean?

> How can I print (access) the array "vel" of machine with
>   "nomeImpianto" = "MFL1"

```
const thisContainsTheDataFromVel = whereYourDataIsStored['ImpiantiProva'].find((item) => { item['nomeImpianto'] === 'MFL1'})['vel'];
```

> and how can I copy the array "vel" on new array?

**UPDATE after reading your comment under this answer:**

I took code from your example and added what you are missing. I made it so it can be more reusable (it can be enhanced even more, but I hope you understand the code and do what you need).

```
copyArray(data, targetValue) {
  const mfl1Data = data.find((item) => item['nomeImpianto'] === targetValue);

  if (mfl1Data) {
    return mfl1Data.vel;
  }

  return [];
}

getdata2() {
    this.http.get<ImpiantoModel[]>(this.myUrl)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.variableToStoreIn = this.copyArray(data, 'MFL1');
          data.forEach(item => {
            this.sub$.next(item);
          });
        });

    return this.sub$;
  }
```

CopyArray finds the data and returns it. If you don't want it like this, but just set a value of some property to the value of vel array then you can change it to:

```
copyArray(data) {
      const mfl1Data = data.find((item) => item['nomeImpianto'] === targetValue);

      if (mfl1Data) {
        this.yourVariable = mfl1Data.vel;
      }
    }
```

If this answer is sufficient, please consider to mark it as the best answer, thank you.

Comment: I upload my [code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/extract-array-from-json-on-angular)  so you can see! I make http request and I fine how to print my array on html template!

But I can't fine how to copy array "vel" to new array. ( see function <code> copyArrary() </code> on <code>app.component.ts</code>. I need to extract array for use the value on other component for generare a charts and I need a array for all the value.

Do you know how can I do? thank you very much!

Comment: * I make http request and I FIND how to print

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your reply! or better, I can not explain well. 
Every 30 second I update the data on stream$. When I click on button "see charts of MFL1" I have to load the charts of this system and for the charts I need 2 array, VEL and ORARIO. The charts have to dinamically load the new data that I add to stream$. So On the charts.component I have to subscribe the 2 array inside stream$. I hope I explained myself better, it's not easy what I want to do! Sharing and subscribing data in this way is complicated and not easy to explain.

Comment: Thank you for your time and for the answers that even if you do not help me any more is still the best.

Comment: What more do you need?

Comment: I wrote a comment with what I need 2 comments over. Where do you copy the array "vel" inside the json on new array? I can't undestand that! We can assume that we have only one item on json after http request I have an array with only "vel", I don't need the other field! Thanks again, I really appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your previous comment. But did you check my updated answer? The copyArray method should do that for you if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to your model classes, your JSON is wrong. You should have something like this:

```
{ "ImpiantiProva": [
        {
        "nomeImpianto":"MFL1",
        "descrImpianto":"Multifilo 1",
        "posizione":"Place1",
        "dati_status": "true",
        "unita_misura": "m/s",
        "vel_attuale": 11.5,

        "vel": [
            {
                "vel": 24.5 
            },
             {
                "vel": 13.6
            }
            ...
        ],
        "orario": [
            {
                "orario": "17.05"   
            },
             {
                "orario": "17.06"
            }
            ...
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Your model expects `ImpiantoModel.vel` and `ImpiantoModel.orario` to be arrays of objects. In your JSON response one is an array of numbers and the other of strings.

An if you want to use it in an HTML template, considering that you have a class attribute in your `.ts` file like this:

```
private impiantoModels: ImpiantoModel[];
```

You could do something like this inside your `.html` template:

```
<div *ngFor="let impModel of impiantoModels">
    ...
    <div *ngFor="let v of impModel.vel">
        <p>{{v.vel}}</p>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let o of impModel.orario">
        <p>{{o.orario}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your reply! unfortunately I can not use the json as you wrote it because in "vel" and "timetable" I have a number of values above 10k.
so I have to use it as an array, as written in my json